# Function with a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've one question.
I've made one function which gives me a random array of colours.

```
function dameColoresRand(numero) {
    i=0;
    colores = [];
    while(i< numero - 1) {
        color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        if(color.length == 7) {
            colores.push(color);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return colores;
}
```

[Sometimes color doesn't has the correct syntax, so I made a simple check]

Well, when I call the function with a loop, for example

```
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    colores = dameColoresRand(10);
    console.log(colores);
}
```

I should see on my console, 3 hex colour code arrays.

Why I only see one array, and nex undefined?

Comment: First thought, you are using the variable `i` in both pieces of code. Neither is scoped with `var` so `i` in the global scope - I assume both pieces of code are messing each other up. tl;dr: always use `var` when declaring a variable in scope.

Comment: Why do you have the `<<0`?

Comment: @squint probably for casting to int.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Oh, you're right. I was thinking the `<<` had higher precedence than the `*`.

Comment: True guys, I was using var i in two places, 1 hour searching this noob error... thanks all !

Comment: just another remark, you are making your random value to a very short range, because you are skipping leading zeroes. maybe think about your algo, because its not realy random in the whole range.

Comment: Please note that `Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF` will never produce `0xFFFFFF` and you are throwing away all results with red values less than `16`

Comment: I've found the algo:
color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
It's not mine, but doues his functions, give me a "rand" hex color :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're sharing the identifier `i`. Two things to address:

```
// inside dameColoresRand()
i=0;
var i = 0;

// before the for loop, add
var i;
// then do the looping
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {...}
```

A bit of explanation of why that's necessary.

In the first case, if you don't precede variable assignments with `var`, you're polluting the global namespace by introducing identifiers: the compiler goes: oh, let me try to find `i`, and it (a) either fails to find `i` (this is what happens initially) and therefore introduces it, or (b) finds the wrong `i` and assigns to it.

In the for loop case, in other languages `{}`s specify a new *scope*, in javascript scope is introduced only by *functions*, so whenever you declare things inside `for`s and `switches`, be aware that those declarations are being lifted to the top of the function's body. So to avoid having these sorts of issues, always declare your variables at the top of the function's body.

Comment: Can confirm. I just tested it in the console and fixed it doing the same thing.

Comment: Nice explanation, Its not bad practice remember the basic programming pillars, thanks you so much !

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine:

```js
function dameColoresRand(numero) {
    var i = 0, color, colores = [];
    while (i < numero - 1) {
        color = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
        if (color.length == 7) {
            colores.push(color);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return colores;
}
var i, colores;
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    colores = dameColoresRand(10);
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colores, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}
```

Comment: You altered critical parts of the code. Maybe you should explain to OP why you did that and what effects that has.

Comment: i did not altered the code, because i always use strict mode, so i thought, the missing declaration was missing here too.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare variables with `var`. Not doing this means that you are declaring a *global* variable.
Therefore you share the variable `i` in the `for` loop and the `function`. 
This causes `i` to be `10` after the first execution of `dameColoresRand`, so the loop skips immediately after that.

```
function dameColoresRand(numero) {
    var i = 0;
    var colores = [];
    while(i < numero - 1) {
        color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        if(color.length == 7) {
            colores.push(color);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return colores;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    colores = dameColoresRand(10);
    console.log(colores);
}
```